# setting the if else condition for filtering data

Tags: c, if-statement, fopen, scanf

i'm getting confused about the if else statement here. My source code is able to fscan the data from txt file and able to printf successfully.

My next step I like to do is setting a if else statement if the src is between 1-1024 and write that line to another txt file else if more than 1024 it should write to another txt file.

I been trying to combine both codes below but unable to get it work.

```
do {
    test = fscanf(inFile, "%d:%d:%d:%d:", &src, &dest, &type, &port);//read line from file
    fgets(data, 100, inFile);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %s", src, dest, type, port, data);

    } while (test != EOF);


if (src >= 1 && src <= 1024){

    FILE *outFile = fopen("data_1.txt", "w");
    fprintf(outFile, "%d %d %d %d %s", "data_1.txt");
    //outFile = cfopen("data_1.txt", "w"); //Open file for writing
    //fprintf("%d %d %d %d %s", src, dest, type, port, data);
}
else {
    fclose(outFile);//must always close file once done
}


fclose(outFile);
fclose(inFile); //must always close file once done

return 0;
```

}

Comment: should the `printf` in the output rountine be `fprintf(outFile, etc)`?  otherwise, you're outputting to stdio, rather than to data_1.txt.

Comment: Why are you calling `fscanf` followed by `fgets`? from the same file pointer? Wouldn't one or the other alone be sufficient?

Comment: @Mike yes i will need to change that printf portion

Comment: @David,it's because the last portion of the data contains character & spaces ... fscanf won't work so i have to use fgets for the last portion

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  What actually happens?  What do you expect to happens?  In both the `src` and `dest` test the code in the (empty) `if` block will be run when the value is between 1 and 1024 inclusively, any other value - including 0, negative numbers and values greater than 1024 - will cause the code in the `else` block to run.

Comment: @MikeofSST The OP needs only if is `greater` not if is `less than`. The OP said "**if more than 1024 it should write to another txt file**". Please read again his Question. So why on Earth should write `0` or negatives numbers in that File, if the OP doesn't need that ?

Comment: **side note** you could change your reading using `fgets()` then `sscanf()` on the read buffer to get out the individual values or use `strtok()/atoi()` instead of `sscanf()`

Answer (score 1):

> else if more than 1024

You said it, you need to use an `else if(src > 1024)`

Comment: This is unnecessary.  The 'else' in the OP handles the cases when the value is greater than 1024; that's exactly what 'else' means.  It also handles cases when the value is 0 or negative, but that's a different issue (probably).

Comment: @MikeofSST How about if the value is `less` ? Let's say `-5`?

Comment: @MikeofSSTwhy did you downvote this Answer ? the OP needed to check only if the value is `greater` and not if  is `less`.

Comment: I'm assuming that @Kotshi meant the code in the answer to be an extension to the code in the question.  i.e. `if(1<=src && src<=1024){ /*do something with 1..1024 values*/ } else if(src > 1024) { /*do something else with values > 1024*/ }`  You could add another `else { /* do something with 0 & -ve values*/ }` to be complete, I suppose.

Comment: @MikeofSST i'm not interested of what he could do, please stick to the question. Why did you down voted that Answer ? please explain

Comment: @MikeofSST Your first comment works like [This](http://ideone.com/4TlS82) and this is not what the OP needed.

Comment: @Michi But that still would not make this a good answer, as the code is incomplete and there is no explanation of why it addresses the OP's question.  As it stands, this answer remains incorrect.

Comment: @MikeofSST I'm agree with that too, this is more a comment then an Answer, but this doesn't make his Answer wrong. It is exactly what the OP needed. Agree?

Comment: @Michi I disagree.  The OP does not mention 0 or negative values at all, which makes this answer a redundant test.  i.e. `if(a=true){} else if(a==false){}`, and that's not a good answer.  My assumption is that they have been overlooked, rather than included by omission.  The fact that the words 'else if' are used in the question does not imply that they're required in the code.  I'll hold out for further clarification from the OP for now.

Comment: @MikeofSST I see that you do not understand my point and I will stop now. Last thing, this is what the OP said =>> "**if more than 1024 it should write to another txt file**"

Comment: @MikeofSST I answered the question, maybe OP was waiting for more but his question wasn't complete enough for us to know what.